# Writing blobs to the blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to write to the blobstore using the method described here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

I tried using the remote_api to execute the following code:

```
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/html',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename='sample.txt')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write('sample text for the sample blob')
files.finalize(file_name)
```

invariably raises the error (at the third line above):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\file
s\file.py", line 310, in write
    self._make_rpc_call_with_retry('Append', request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\file
s\file.py", line 388, in _make_rpc_call_with_retry
    _make_call(method, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\file
s\file.py", line 236, in _make_call
    _raise_app_error(e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\file
s\file.py", line 179, in _raise_app_error
    raise FileNotOpenedError()
FileNotOpenedError
```

The file i am trying to write is very small (< 20KB) so its not a quota issue.  Are there additional steps i am missing?

Comment: You seem to be trying to do this from an interactive shell, too. Where? What code are you entering?

Comment: Updated the code and yes i am executing via remote api.  I need to do that because i need to create blobs using my custom bulkloader.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can need to add below module but if you dont previously add.

```
    from __future__ import with_statement 
 -->from google.appengine.api import files
    from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers


    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/plain',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename='sample.txt')
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
         f.write('sample text for the sample blob') 
    files.finalize(file_name)
```